# Существует ли такая библиотека Python, которая позволила бы считывать данные приложения?

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

- Я совсем недавно озадачился этой темой, искал в интернете, но особых знаний в том, что именно мне надо найти и изучить, нету.
- Допустим, что есть какая-то программа, которая работает в режиме онлайн (игра: Dota 2, CS:GO и тд)
- Нужно получить данные из окна приложения, чтобы потом эти данные использовать для дальнейшего анализа
- **Есть вот такой скриншот:**  [image: Скриншот окна приложения]
- Мне нужно получить данные, которые на скриншоте в окне "Рынок" и при этом делать это динамически, т.е при скролле мышкой читать эти данные и записывать, например, в таблицы

**Какие библиотеки в Python мне могут помочь?**

Comment: `win32api` - если это виндовое окно (только перерисованное), то сможете добраться до нужных элементов

Comment: т.е с помощью этой библиотеки я смогу добраться до данных, которые находятся в окне? Тогда ли не проще писать на "с/с++"?

Comment: зависит от задачи - вы же на одном языке пишите, а не скрещиваете несколько языков в одном приложении (хотя и можно - модуль на одном, библиотека на другом, интерфейс на третьем)

хотите - используйтеc++, смысл не изменится